# mysql getting result from two identical table

Tags: mysql, performance, compare

I have two identical tables. I want to compare these two tables and getting the result from them. The condition are:

1. each record in TABLE1 **grouped by TID** will be compared to all records in TABLE2 **grouped by their each TID**.
2. if each **grouped** record in TABLE1 are to be discovered in TABLE2 (records in TABLE2 that grouped by each tid, too), as many as N (N is the user input variable), then that record will be inserted into new table.

For example, like the ss below, **ITEM C-F-A** grouped by **TID 2** has 3 occurrences in table2, thus they will be inserted into new table:

[image]

I've already tried writing the code for this and it worked (vb.net), but the compiler takes ridiculous time to complete. The main cause is I'm processing a huge database.

The method I've done in program is populate the two table into 2d array. assigning value to array while comparing the two element with `if clause`.

Below is the 2d array that I've created:

[image]

But this method is really expensive, **my real database on pic above is 1st 2d array has 2k records and 2nd 2d array has 800 records**, and when I try to calculate the estimate time for compiling to completed, it showed a fantastic number, about 16 hours.. gosh!!

So I was wondering, whether this problem can be solved with mysql query,
or other method that is more effective than what I have done?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acheive?  Are you just trying to mirror the tables?  Are these in the same or different database?

Comment: its on the same database.. two identical table with same fields. what i wanna achieve is selecting **grouped of records with TID as identifier** in TABLE1 which has certain number of occurences in TABLE2. simply said, each records grouped by TID in TABLE1 will be checked for their frequency in TABLE2.. if certain number of frequency has been reached, the grouped records in TABLE1 will be inserted into new table

Comment: @GrandmasterB he wants to do a merge operation but I don't know MySQL so I can't speak to weather it has such functionality or how it would be done. Also he wants to do the merge operation based on a complex aggregate which makes it even less likely to be a set operation, this is probably going to have to be done relatively imperatively with an interstitial table

Comment: Ah, I see.  So basically, for each group id in table 1, if there exists a number of rows in table 2 with that same group id above some specified count, add those rows to table 1.  A practical application might be waiting for a vehicle to fill with enough passengers or packages before sending it on its way.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tbl3 
  SELECT tbl1.TID, tbl1.ITEM 
  FROM tbl1 
    JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.TID = tbl1.TID AND tbl2.ITEM = tbl1.ITEM
```

This will insert a record into tbl3 for each record in tbl1 that has a corresponding record in tbl2 identified by TID and ITEM.

This assumes that TID/ITEM is a unique index in both tbl1 and tbl2.

Comment: hi @Rob, thx for answering..
unfortunately TID and ITEM acts as a normal field without PK or FK relation here. and the insertion condition isn't only if **TABLE1.grouped_records*& does exist in **TABLE2.grouped_records**.. but it also needs certain number of matches between two table, thus it will be a valid condition to insert into new table

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a wild, untested, guess (WUG).

The approach goes like this:

- You need a list of TID's from table1.  So you build a distinct list (inner most query).
- You use that list in a where clause when selecting from table2, so that you only get rows that have TIDs in table1.  You group that query, and use HAVING to then limit the rows to only those with a count > X.
- Now you have a list of TIDs that match those in table1 and have more than X entries in table2.  You select those rows.
- Those are used a the source of an insert statement into table1.

The SQL might looks something like:

```
    insert into table1 
      values (select * from table2 where tid in 
        (select tid, count(*) as cnt 
            from table2 
            where tid in (select distinct tid from table1) 
            group by tid
            having cnt > 10)));
```

I doubt the syntax is correct (cant remember the exact syntax for an insert from a select), and make no claim it will work off the bat, but its what my first shot would be if I wanted to do it all in one query.

Comment: hi @GrandmasterB is the `WHERE IN CLAUSE` means to select GROUPED ITEM BY TID from **table2** that only match with GROUPED ITEM BY TID in **table1**? then wouldn't your query will be only select **matched count of tid** instead of **matched element of tid**? i mean if TABLE1 has TID 2 that has 3 count, then it will also search for matched **TID with 3 count** in TABLE2 then? what i mean is TABLE1 TID2 got **C-F-A**, thus it will search for TIDs contain **C-F-A** in TABLE2. and the query still has an error at `WHERE IN`, i've tried to fix it, using `ALIAS` but it didn't worked either. thx u

Comment: It would select all rows from table2 who's tid is also found in table1.  Another thing you might consider is setting up some views, making the sql more straight forward.